# what happens with if == statement with no arguments?

Tags: c

With

`if (i==1) {something}`  - program will execute something on true

what happens with

`if (i==1)`              - will it break or do nothing on false?

I've seen program with

`if (id == 0x11)` //OK

with no {} and don't know if it does something. I think it should use next line as its "insides" but it wouldn't change anything

Comment: I see you had tagged microcontrollers in your post. An if statement with absolutely no body should still affect the flag register. Like in this case the Carry Flag.
https://betterprogramming.pub/heres-how-the-cpu-handles-if-statements-and-branching-95cfd42af9c

Comment: Please provide a complete example (like a whole function), something you have actually compiled (or if it fails to compile, include the error).

Comment: code is from post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59215546/stm32f4-losting-samples-of-fifo-data-from-max30100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next statement will be used as the if block. Opening brace does not necessarily be on the same line with the if, and a single statement if does not need to use opening and closing braces. All of the following are equivalent:

```
if (expression) // OK
{
    statement1;
}

if (expression) { statement1;}

if (expression)
    statement1;
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is ([C11 6.8.4](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.4))

```
if (<condition>) <statement>
```

where `<condition>` is some expression with a value compatible to `int`
and
`<statement>` is a regular statement or a block statement.

```
if (foo == 42) return 4; // regular statement ends with semicolon
if (bar == foo) { puts("nope!"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } // block statement
```

And, remember that whitespace is not significant in C text source

```
if (a == b)

b = 0;
```

is equal to

```
if (a == b) b = 0;
```